# Vuetify v-calendar: Dynamic Daily Interval does not work on Safari

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

**The Issue:**
I Did use the Vuetify Calendar to build up a calendar.
The daily interval in Day View should be different according to business opening times that day.
The logic works for Firefox and Chrome. But not on Safari.

**The working example:**
Here is a Codepen i build to demonstrate the issue. When clicking on day View and moving between days there are different time ranges within the day. The Pen works on FF and Chrome, but not on Safari.
https://codepen.io/ttezcan/pen/KKzjEMM
This is the main method that changes interval dynamically:

```
setIntervalByWeekday(weekday) {
            console.log(weekday);                
       if (weekday === 7) {
         weekday = 0;                    
       }                  
       if (weekday === -1) {           
         weekday = 6;
       }
                            
       this.weekday = weekday;
                            
       let start = this.bussiness_hours[weekday]['start'];
                            
       let end = this.bussiness_hours[weekday]['end'];
               
       var timeStart = new Date('2020-05-19 ' + start).getHours();
                            
       var timeEnd = new Date('2020-05-19 ' + end).getHours();
                            
       var duration = timeEnd - timeStart;
       this.firstInterval = start;
       this.intervalCount = duration;                  
     },
```

**What i tried:** 
My research showed that the problem in Safari occurs when changing the values for 
:first-interval="firstInterval" and 
:interval-count="intervalCount"
dynamically.

I tried using computed props to force rerender of component.
I tried calling this.$refs.calendar.checkChange() to force rerender.

Anyone has an idea how to make this work for Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Vuetify dev had the answer:

```
new Date('2020-05-19 ' + start).getHours()
```

Chrome parses that as the system timezone and returns hours in the system timezone. Safari parses it as UTC and return hours in the system timezone. Use luxon or date-fns if you need to do arithmetic on dates.

Thx @KaelWD